# How detect object in opencv in android

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

### Find object/marker also give distance from camera using android and `OpenCV`.

**Detecting all object like the image below**
[image]

**And Get Distance from camera to object**
[image]

Comment: Plz tell us what do you mean by detecting objects bcz definition of **objects** can vary according to the application.Second thing is it is impossible to detect the distance of an object with a single camera. Third show us what have you tried your algorithm/code.

Comment: to get the distance between the cam and the object you need to take a look into camera calibration( you may be able to do that using only one cam). localizing an object is a different subject, you need to define, which aspects define your object .

Comment: take a look at https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/mastering-opencv-practical-computer-vision-projects